# Why isn't mysqli working in different php files

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First of all I'm sorry if my english is not perfect, english is not my mother language. I'll try my best to make myself understood.

I'm trying to create all the necessary steps to connect and query a database using mysqli. These will stay in a separate php file that will be included whenever necessary. I'm doing this just to save having to always write the code to connect to the database.

In my dbConnection.php file I have:

```
<?php
require("login.php");

$connection;
function connect() {
    global $connection;

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($connection->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $connection->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
}

function mysqlQuery($query) {
    global $connection;

    if($connection == NULL) connect();

    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Query failed: %s\n", $connection->error);
        exit();
    }

    return $result;
}

?>
```

(login.php has the variables for connection)

When I need to connect to a database I use require("dbConnection.php");

The problem is when I call the mysqlQuery function it always prints "Query failed: No database selected". I'm pretty sure the database name is correct.

When I use the code directly in the script (not in separate files) it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Problem has been solved, forgot to declare as global $host, $username, $password, $database.**

Comment: You mean $connection->error and not $mysqli->error, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Bad copy paste. The error printed is: No database selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons for one's code to go wrong:

1. Wrong idea or algorithm or structure
2. Wrong *implementation* of that idea or algorithm or structure

Inexperienced programmers always stuck with the first one and pay little attention to the second (so you ask - "How to use...?"). While in the real life second one is more important. Algorithms are few but mistakes are countless. One have to learn how to spot mistakes.

Although I see no point in such structure, (mysqlQuery function practically useless and can be substituted with `$result = $connection->query($query) or trigger_error($connection->error."[$query]");` line of code, which would be **way** better), at first sight it should work.
Thus, we have to concentrate not on the "How to do it?" question but on "Why doesn't it work?".

The answer to the latter question is called *debugging*. You have to learn it and heavily use in your daily work. In practice that means that you have to check every variable in your code if it contain desired value.

To see all the errors generated by PHP is also essential for the debugging.
Always have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` directive in your code (in a global config file would be fine).

And also, on a development system add `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to your config file (but change value to 0 on production!)

I bet these two directives will shed some light on the problem.
If not - continue debugging.

Comment: Hello. Yes, the function is practically useless as it is right now, it's just the beginning of it. The goal is to add a lot more stuff to it, I was just testing a simple connection and query to the database. I'm sorry if the question was not properly made, I guess "why" is a better way to put it. I'm new to php and I didn't know how to debug without prints (which weren't giving me much) and since I didn't found an answer I though I should ask. I'm sorry if I was offensive in some way :/ Thanks for the tips.